# Trying to install my main electrical to my mobile home from the Eaton distribution panel meter box post outside that has a meter

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a 200 amp Max meter box outside. It says recreational temporary use and has a 200 amp breaker inside with a RV plug and a 110 plug.
I also want to hook up my single wide small mobile home to this box and be able to use power for electric hot water heater, dryer, stove and average outlet usage for a single person.
I have a box that I want to install in the mobile home that has a 200 amp breaker as well and wire that is 446 type SE.
Am I doing it right or do I need to make changes?

My main meter service from pole:
[![My main meter service from pole][1]][1]

My outside main service from pole to property
[image: My outside main service from pole to property]

Comment: It appears that you've posted the same picture twice. Please double check your images and [edit] to correct.

Comment: Generally, these mobile homes are pre-constructed with a service panel already in them. Don't you want to use that? (there's a way you can, and then you won't have to rewire a bunch of stuff that's already wired).

Comment: No this home was severely damaged and all the wiring has been cut by people that tried to occupy it before I bought this so that is all like deleted and obsolete I need to start fresh I must start fresh